# Disable every rss feed except home feed

Tags: functions, feed

I would like to disable every feed (comments, category, tags, author) as detailed here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/ except for the "home-page feed" that you can found here:

http://example.com/feed/

It is important also removing links to the feeds in the head of the document.

I've found multiple articles on how to remove feeds globally (https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/), but nothing on how to remove only selected ones without writing hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
// remove_author_feed_link( $link, $feed );
// As we do not pass $link and $feed is empty by default, function just exits
function remove_author_feed_link() {
    return;
}
add_filter( 'author_feed_link', 'remove_author_feed_link' );


function remove_category_feed_link() {
    return;
}
add_filter( 'category_feed_link', 'remove_category_feed_link');


function remove_search_feed_link() {
    return;
}
add_filter( 'search_feed_link', 'remove_search_feed_link' );


function remove_tag_feed_link() {
    return;
}
add_filter( 'tag_feed_link', 'remove_tag_feed_link' );


// Removes Post Comments Feed
function remove_comments_feed_link() {
    return;
}
add_filter( 'post_comments_feed_link', 'remove_comments_feed_link' );


// Removes global Comments Feed
add_filter( 'feed_links_show_comments_feed', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: your function leave intact the feed page for categories and so on...

Comment: example.com/category/feed is still working